How to find/create configuration file in OpenVPN?
I pasted the url to VPS: bash <(curl -fsS https://as-repository.openvpn.net/as/install.sh), made sure logins are correct, copied them. After I tried to connect it to the router, but I needed a configuration file, but in the internet was not information directly about this question
